# Android OS installation to tablet

Tags: applications, installation

I have a tablet X touch, But its operating system has been damaged. Now I want to install fresh one to it. How can it be done? Someone help please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "damaged"? Does the tablet boot up? What is the exact problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @Wajid Ali, I suggest you to report to nearest Customer Care for that device; in case you are not responsible ;)

Answer (score 1):

Find the firmware for your specific model of tablet [via this search](http://www.xtouchdevice.com/en/support_find.php?cateid=14), then download the firmware image and the tools listed, and follow the instructions to flash the firmware onto the device.

Comment: @Dan Hulme's contribution is notable. The asker has not specified whether he is responsible for the bricking or not. If not then he would better report to customer care unless the device has not overpassed the warranty.